# How to get size of sqlite database in Titanium

Tags: sqlite, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I need to get size of sqlite database, like this:

```
var db = Ti.Database.open('test');
//db.size();
//size doesn't works
```

the size() method does not exist, how can I do to get the size ? Is there any other way I can do to get the size of the db ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The database is stored in a file, which you can get the size of. So, db.file will return a handle to the file and then getting the size of the file is simply the size property. I think this should work: db.file.size

Ray

Comment: I did so : var size = Ti.Database.open('testDb').getFile().size(); but it did not work, any tips ? - TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,18753] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<TiDatabase> has no method 'getFile'